# i need to get a user id from a query result

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, relational-database

am querying from my User table using the user name, how do i get the user id from the query object
User.where(user_name: "john")

my goal is to get the User id: 5, i thought it was as easy as (.id), but thats not working

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 5, user_name: "john", user_city: "India", created_at: "2019-01-19 18:02:32", updated_at: "2019-01-19 18:02:32">]>
```

Comment: *i thought it was as easy as (.id), but thats not working*. Exactly what did you try and what was the error? `.id` on a *single record* should work just fine. Note that `.where` will return a *collection* of records, so the collection won't recognize `.id`. If there's just one, you could do, `User.where(user_name: 'john').first.id`.

Answer (score 4):

Materialized `where` will return a collection, so you can get first record with `.first`

```
User.where(:user_name => "john").first&.id
```

Or use `find_by` which will return first record which satisfies condition.

```
User.find_by(:user_name => "john")&.id
```

Comment: @lurker, `object&.attribute` is Safe Navigation Operator. By using it on the object exception will not be thrown if object is `nil`, instead `nil` value will be propagated as return value.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I hadn't seen the notation before. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're really only trying to get the id (i.e., not using any other attributes of the object) it's usually better to formulate this as a [`.pluck`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck). This requires [less time for ActiveRecord](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck) to instantiate, and makes the query job take better use of your database indices. As long as `User#user_name` is unique (and I'd hope so!) it will return an array of length 1.

```
User.where(user_name: "John").first.&id 
   # SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."user_name" = "John" 
   # ORDER BY "users" ASC LIMIT 1
   # => 1 or nil

User.where(user_name: "John").pluck(:id).first
   # SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" WHERE "users"."user_name" = "John"
   # => 1 or nil
```

Unfortunately, `find_by` and its helpers don't work this way with `pluck`, and both of these statements instead result in errors

```
User.find_by(user_name: "John").pluck(:id)
User.find_by_user_name("John").pluck(:id)
```